# How to export millions of rows into Sharepoint 2013 list

Tags: excel, oracle, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, archive

I am facing an issue when trying to export data to SharePoint 2013 lists. The requirement is to archive data from oracle to SharePoint 2013.

I have tried two approaches

1. Connect MS Access to Oracle and export to SharePoint list.
2. Export data from Oracle to Excel and from excel import to SharePoint.

Both the option is not working for huge data.
Maximum data which I was able to import was 1,00,000 records but the requirement is to import 10 million data to SharePoint list.

Experts, please suggest how it can be achieved.

Comment: I don't know much about SharePoint, but last I checked, Excel has a hard coded limit of approximately 1 million rows and Access has a hard coded limit of 2 GB.

Comment: You could do it in chunks. If you are using `PL/SQL`, then keep a `counter` and do it accordingly.

Comment: I can do in chunks but need a consolidated view where user can see all the data from all the chunks at one place and can even filter data.

Comment: Agree with @LalitKumarB you can upload data in chunks, however check [capability boundaries of Sharepoint 2013](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12438.sharepoint-2013-best-practices.aspx#Capacity_Planning)

Comment: Thanks to everyone. just one more query, what is the limit while importing data to list?and can we generate a combined view for data in chunks?

Comment: IMHO 10 Million Items are just too many if you importing it to a single List albeit SharePoint 2013 Limits says 30 Million are supported depending upon the number of columns (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ListLibrary), anyways if you manage to import, I imagine you will need to provide some sort of custom screens for navigation around such a list and not use OOB List Views, there are number of options including using ContentIterator class to navigate through a large list programmatically